# VBA - copying to other sheets

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have this code, by a responder who helped me to define my needs yesterday - but there somethings i want to change, but my vba skills are very low and dont know how and where to modify the code. I want it do 2 Things.

1. Right know it transferes data, i want it to copy it, over with the values that are calculated in the cells. I have some cells, where i have some formulas and it dosent follows with it. I just want the calculated value over. I dont know if i can use `xlPasteValues` somewhere to get what i want?

   2. The second thing that i want is, when copying over, i want to be on top and the previous copies move Down, so the latest copy always are in the top.

Thank you before handed :)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copypastemeddata()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")

    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to

    With ws

          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)

          Dim nextRow As Long
          nextRow = GetLastRow(targetSheet, 1)
          nextRow = IIf(nextRow = 1, 1, nextRow + 1)

         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & nextRow)
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit

    End With

End Sub


Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal ws As Worksheet, Optional ByVal columnNumber As Long = 1) As Long

    With ws

      GetLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, columnNumber).End(xlUp).Row

    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try...

The StartRow variable defines the destination row on targetSheet, you may change it as per your requirement.

```
Sub Copypastemeddata()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sourceCell As Range
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim StartRow As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Opgørsel")

    Set sourceCell = ws.Range("D3")  'Cell with sheet names for copying to
    StartRow = 1    'Destination row on targetSheet
    With ws
          Set targetSheet = wb.Worksheets(sourceCell.Text)
         .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).Insert shift:=xlDown
         targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
         targetSheet.Columns.AutoFit
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = 0
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, that was excatly, what i wanted :)

Comment: @MzBarcaaa You're welcome! Glad it worked as desired. :)

Comment: @MzBarcaaa You selected it first as an accepted answer and then removed it. Any reason?

Comment: I thought, that i could upvote both of them - I used yours and are very happy by it - Thank you, i have now changed it :)

Comment: Thanks! Otherwise I was confused. Lol

Comment: What should i add, if i want the formulas in the cells to come with it, when it is copied over?

Comment: In that case, just remove the line `targetSheet.Range("A" & StartRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`

Comment: Thank you, what about the reference in the formula that is in the sheet - I have a big database where it finds the some numbers that are calculated in the formulas in the cells - I want to still use the reference to the database, when everything is copied over - Maybe i should make a quetions? :D

Comment: That's correct. It would be better if you open a new question. :)

Answer (score 0):

substitute

```
      Dim nextRow As Long
      nextRow = GetLastRow(targetSheet, 1)
      nextRow = IIf(nextRow = 1, 1, nextRow + 1)

     .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & nextRow)
```

with

```
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        targetSheet.Rows(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Insert shift:=xlUp
        targetSheet.Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
    End With
```

Comment: keep @sktneer answer as accepted, but consider using this code since it doesn't use clipboard (as `Copy()` method does, hence requiring `Application.CutCopyMode = 0` stuff)) which is always something you want to avoid when possible

Comment: Maybe i will try it later, but right know the one i use Works fine - so i will let it bet that may, im afraid getting some errors :D